# How to go back to previous step in c++

Tags: c++

I am a C++ beginner and I am making a tool where I can access all my selfmade tools. But the problem is that if I press something and go back I can't choose another option.
for example if I choose '3' and go back I cannot acces '1' or '2' Does someone know a solution? I want to do this with multiply steps.
thanks!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::cin;
int main()

{
    string username;
    string password;
    string secondchoice;
    string passwd="",user;
    string firstchoice;
    cout << "www.mytools.com\n\nWelcome to MyTools!";
    getchar();
    cout << "\nlogin [1]";
    cout << "\nabout us [2]";
    cout << "\ncontact [3]";
    cout << "\nMake your choice: ";
    cin >> firstchoice;
    system("CLS"); 

    firstchoice = " ";
while (firstchoice != "q")
{
    cin >> firstchoice;
    if (firstchoice == "1")
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "username: ";
        cin >> username;
        cout << "password: ";
        cin >> password;
        if (username == "myusername" && password == "mypassword") {     
            system("cls");
            cout << "You are succesfully logged in as "; cout << username; cout << "!";
        }
        else {
            cout << "username or password incorrect! press enter to try again. "; 
            string enter;
            getch();
            system("cls");
        }
        cout << "username: ";
        cin >> username;
        cout << "password: ";
        cin >> password;
        if (username == "myusername" && password == "mypassword") 
        {
             system("cls");
             cout << "You are succesfylly loggen in as "; cout << username; cout << "!"; 
        }
        else {
            cout << "You have been blocked from the server for to many tries\n";
            return 0; 
        }
    }


    if (firstchoice == "2") {
        system("cls"); 
        cout << "some stuff";
        getch();
        system("cls");

        cout << "\nlogin [1]";
        cout << "\nabout us [2]";
        cout << "\ncontact [3]";
        cout << "\nMake your choice: ";
        cin >> firstchoice;
        system("CLS"); 
    }

    if (firstchoice == "3") {
        system("cls");
        cout << "some stuff";
        getch();
        system("cls");
        cout << "welcome to MyTools!";
        getch();
        cout << "\nlogin [1]";
        cout << "\nabout us [2]";
        cout << "\ncontact [3]";
        cout << "\nMake your choice: ";
        cin >> firstchoice;
    system("CLS"); }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Design your code so that you're using functions, and not stick everything inside of `main`.  If you had a simple function `showMenu()` to show/reshow the menu and `getChoice()` that gets a choice from the menu, then your code would be more manageable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your comment. I think that I am now not good enough in C++ to do that., but if I am further I will try that!

Comment: It looks like you are populating the `firstchoice` twice - once in the beginning of the while loop and once when you prompt the user at the end of choices 2 and 3. You only need the one in the beginning. And please decompose your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are populating the firstchoice twice - once in the beginning of the while loop and once when you prompt the user at the end of choices 2 and 3. You only need the one in the beginning. And I would recommend decomposing your code a bit like shown.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::cin;


string getChoice() {
    cout << "\nlogin [1]";
    cout << "\nabout us [2]";
    cout << "\ncontact [3]";
    cout << "\nMake your choice: ";
    string choice;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

int main() {
    string username;
    string password;
    string secondchoice;
    string passwd = "", user;
    string firstchoice;
    cout << "www.mytools.com\n\nWelcome to MyTools!";
    getchar();

    system("CLS");

    firstchoice = " ";
    while (firstchoice != "q")
    {
        firstchoice = getChoice();
        if (firstchoice == "1")
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "username: ";
            cin >> username;
            cout << "password: ";
            cin >> password;
            if (username == "myusername" && password == "mypassword") {
                system("cls");
                cout << "You are succesfully logged in as "; cout << username; cout << "!";
            }
            else {
                cout << "username or password incorrect! press enter to try again. ";
                string enter;
                system("cls");
            }
            cout << "username: ";
            cin >> username;
            cout << "password: ";
            cin >> password;
            if (username == "myusername" && password == "mypassword")
            {
                system("cls");
                cout << "You are succesfylly loggen in as "; cout << username; cout << "!";
            }
            else {
                cout << "You have been blocked from the server for to many tries\n";
                return 0;
            }
        } else if (firstchoice == "2") {
            system("cls");
            cout << "some stuff";
            system("cls");
        } else if (firstchoice == "3") {
            system("cls");
            cout << "some stuff";
            system("cls");
            cout << "welcome to MyTools!";
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a string firstchoice. So, you can change every while to if and make a while loop `while (firstchoice != "q")` and place `cin>> firstchoice;`  in that while loop.

```
firstchoice = " ";
while (firstchoice != "q")
{
    std::cin >> firstchoice;
    if (firstchoice == "1")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::cin;
int main()

{
    string username;
    string password;
    string secondchoice;
    string passwd = "", user;
    string firstchoice;
    cout << "www.mytools.com\n\nWelcome to MyTools!";
    getchar();
    cout << "\nlogin [1]";
    cout << "\nabout us [2]";
    cout << "\ncontact [3]";
    cout << "\nMake your choice: ";
    cin >> firstchoice;
    system("CLS");

    firstchoice = " ";
    while (firstchoice != "q")
    {
        cin >> firstchoice;
        if (firstchoice == "1")
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "username: ";
            cin >> username;
            cout << "password: ";
            cin >> password;
            if (username == "myusername" && password == "mypassword") {
                system("cls");
                cout << "You are succesfully logged in as "; cout << username; cout << "!";
            }
            else {
                cout << "username or password incorrect! press enter to try again. ";
                string enter;
                system("cls");
            }
            cout << "username: ";
            cin >> username;
            cout << "password: ";
            cin >> password;
            if (username == "myusername" && password == "mypassword")
            {
                system("cls");
                cout << "You are succesfylly loggen in as "; cout << username; cout << "!";
            }
            else {
                cout << "You have been blocked from the server for to many tries\n";
                return 0;
            }
        }


        if (firstchoice == "2") {
            system("cls");
            cout << "some stuff";
            system("cls");

            cout << "\nlogin [1]";
            cout << "\nabout us [2]";
            cout << "\ncontact [3]";
            cout << "\nMake your choice: ";
        }

        if (firstchoice == "3") {
            system("cls");
            cout << "some stuff";
            system("cls");
            cout << "welcome to MyTools!";
            cout << "\nlogin [1]";
            cout << "\nabout us [2]";
            cout << "\ncontact [3]";
            cout << "\nMake your choice: ";

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I get it. Did you mean "q" instead of " "? What I now have is this but it is just saying 'press enter to continue' if (firstchoice == "3") {
        system("cls");
        cout << "some stuff";
        getch();
        system("cls");
        cout << "welcome to MyTools!";
        getch();
        cout << "\nlogin [1]";
        cout << "\nabout us [2]";
        cout << "\ncontact [3]";
    cout << "\nMake your choice: "; }
        
system("CLS"); }
    return 0;
    }

Comment: It can be any character. Or another option is bool variable and same logic. Can you describe what you have because I dont get your comment

Comment: I have edited my post to what I got now. Now it is saying nothing if I choose '1', '2' or '3'. If I press q it is finished.

Comment: So, I removed getch() and system("cls"); in the end of 2 and 3 if and it worked for me

Comment: You shouldn't do system("cls") at the end of if because you will anyway clear everything at the start of every if

Comment: thanks for you help! with your help and Varun's help together I have finally solved it..